# Select ids based on conditions on multiple rows

Tags: mysql

I have a table that looks like this

```
Tag_Id    Bid     Category   Title
  1        1        Toys     Ludo
  2        1        Toys     Snakes
  3        2        Food     Potato
  4        1        Food     Chicken
  5        1        Name     Chris
  6        2        Name     Joe
```

I want to write a query which finds Bid based on the following condition.

```
Find Bid's where 
(
    (Category = "Toys" AND Title = "Ludo") 
    OR 
    (Category = "Toys" AND Title = "Snakes")
) 
AND (Category = "Food" AND Title = "Potato") 
AND 
(
    (Category = "Name" AND Title = "Chris") 
    OR 
    (Category = "Name" AND Title = "Joe")
)
```

Notice that there are ORs between same categories and ANDs between different categories. Is there any way to achieve this with single query?

Comment: may b `mysql case` statement help u :http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html

Comment: Can you describe the expected output required for the above sample data.

Comment: Expected output would be bid 1

Comment: So, if the request has to return 1, what I have written down outputs what you want, no ?

Comment: No, it doesn't because the query written below would try to find all the categories and titles on a single row and not on multiple rows. And a single row in the above table only contains one category and one title

Comment: OK, I think the simply method is to use other langage to do this. Which language do you use with mysql ? PHP ?

Comment: Could you explain why the result would be bid 1?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Bid 
FROM yourTable 
WHERE ( (Category = "Toys" AND Title = "Ludo") OR (Category = "Toys" AND Title = "Snakes") )
AND (Category = "Food" AND Title = "Potato") 
AND ( (Category = "Name" AND Title = "Chris") OR (Category = "Name" AND Title = "Joe") )
```

You have already written the most difficult.

Comment: This would not find Bids across multiple rows. Kind of relational division problem

Comment: So, I think, I don't understand what you want the request returns

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
SELECT  Bid FROM bidTable WHERE Category = "Toys"
UNION
SELECT  Bid FROM bidTable WHERE Category = "Food"
UNION
SELECT  Bid FROM bidTable WHERE Category = "Name"
```

i think u get all the rows shown in question then why so much condition..btw u can add condition in `WHERE` clause